# How to tell what caused about:blank to be blocked by IE Enhanced Security Configuration?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

On my site that used jquery/bootstrap/knockout IE10 on Windows Server 2012 (mostly tested with it although the same error happens on Win2008 etc.) IE throws an error saying that Enhanced Security Configuration blocked content from `about:blank`.

What does IE consider to be coming from `about:blank`?

I have put a `<noscript>` on the page which works fine while the page itself is not in a normal security zone but people who have unchecked the `Continue to prompt...` will never see any errors and some pieces of the site will just stop working while others work fine.

[image: IE ESC]

Comment: probably somewhere in the code an iframe is being set to `about:blank`

Comment: @epascarello - an `<iframe src="about:blank">` does not trigger this error - I have checked and the error does not appear on pages where such iframe exists and does appear even after I remove them on other pages.

Comment: Is there a `window.open("about:blank")`? That can trigger it.

Comment: @epascarello - there is not. `about:blank` is not even mentioned once in the source code of the website.

Comment: Are the knockout templates being loaded from iframes with empty sources?

Comment: I've hit this behaviour when calling jQuery's `.html`, it's mentioned in this jQuery bug report: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13074

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After line by line debugging I found out that the following combination of conditions result in the error. It is probably not the exclusive reason but it also allowed me to write code that displays a warning to the user.

```
// 1. create an element but do not add it to the DOM
var elem = document.createElement("div");
// 2. set its innerHTML to something that contains script. 
//    in this line IE shows the error although the code continues.
elem.innerHTML = "<span onclick=\"alert()\">aa</span>";

// 3. add to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(elem);
// in order to fix the issue, move item #3 right after #1.
```

If the element is added to the DOM before setting `.innerHTML`, it works fine. The thing to notice is that the code actually completes and after it if you check `.innerHTML` you will actually see the `onclick` handler intact. The problem is that it will not be parsed and will not executed when you click the element.

So using this I created the following code that shows a warning to the user.

```
var test = document.createElement("div");
test.innerHTML = "<span onclick=\"window.B264E0BD67794ED9949FCF91D654F54F=1;\"></span>";
test.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].click();
if (!window.B264E0BD67794ED9949FCF91D654F54F)
    alert("Your browser is configured to use Enhanced Security Configuration which is not compatible with this website.");
```